# Pay.jpでトークン取れない

Tags: jquery

Pay.jpのカスタムフォームを実装しようとしています。
フォームから各種値を取得してcreateTokenしていますが、「Invalid expiration year」となってトークンが取得できません。コードは以下のとおりです。

```
  $(function() {
    $('#checkout_form_payment').submit(function() {
      var card, cvc, exp_month, exp_year, expire, number;
      number = $('#card_number').val();
      cvc = $('#card_code').val();
      expire = $('#card_expiry').val();
      exp_month = expire.substr(0, 2);
      exp_year = expire.substr(5, 2);

      card = {
        number: number,
        cvc: cvc,
        exp_month: exp_month,
        exp_year: exp_year
      };
      alert(JSON.stringify(card));
      Payjp.createToken(card, function(s, response) {
        var token;
        if (response.error) {
          alert(response.error.message);
          return false;
        } else {
          alert("res=" + response.id);
          token = response.id;
          $('#checkout_form_payment').append($('<input type="hidden" name="payjpToken" />').val(token));
          $('#checkout_form_payment').submit();
        }
        return
```

入力しているのは以下の値です。

```
      number = '4242424242424242';
      cvc = '123';
      expire = '12 / 20';
```

なのでexp_yearは２０です。どこが問題でしょうか？
一応フォームのソースは長いので割愛します。それぞれ値が取れているところまでは確認しています。

Answer (score 1):

このAPIリファレンス [Token (トークン)](https://pay.jp/docs/api/#token-%E3%83%88%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AF%E3%83%B3) によると、有効期限年の情報は、西暦4桁のようです。
頭に"20"を補って指定してみてください。

curlでの例

> ```
> curl https://api.pay.jp/v1/tokens \
> -u sk_test_c62fade9d045b54cd76d7036: \
> -H "X-Payjp-Direct-Token-Generate: true" \
> -d "card[number]=4242424242424242" \
> -d "card[cvc]=123" \
> -d "card[exp_month]=02" \
> -d "card[exp_year]=2020"
> ```

Nodeでの例

> ```
> var payjp = require('payjp')('sk_test_c62fade9d045b54cd76d7036');
> payjp.tokens.create(
>     query = { 
>       card: { 
>         number: 4242424242424242,
>         cvc: 123,
>         exp_month: 2,
>         exp_year: 2020
>         },
>       },
>     headers = {
>      'X-Payjp-Direct-Token-Generate': 'true'  
>     }  
> );
> ```

Comment: ありがとうございます！ビンゴでした。